# Combine data from multiple sheets and update automatically to Summary sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to create summary sheet that will only take data from other sheets. I have 10 sheets which has data in rows from 1 to 100+ (Sheet 1 has 102 rows and Sheet 7 has 1 row etc.) Every sheet has the same format and columns.

So the summary sheet should take data from sheet 1, row 5 till no data. If there is no data in sheet then switch to next sheet and start from row 5 till no data etc.

It would be best to have all the columns (A-P) but it'll be useful even only with column D and L as well.

If possible it would be nice to not have duplicates in summary sheet - there are few same data values in different sheets and rest of the duplicates can be skipped.

I have tried to combine data with formulas, consolidate, pivot. None of them seems right - I might do it wrong. The solution can be made with formula or as a pivot table -style, no matter. Can't figure out how to create sustainable automation to get data from row 5 till no data and switch to next sheet and repeat.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `VSTACK()` to stack data from others sheet to summery sheet. They use other formula to get desired result.

Comment: If that was me I would use Power Query

Comment: Besides Power Query, I can't see this happening without VBA. If that's of your interest, add the `vba` tag at the bottom of your post. Also, explain what makes a row a duplicate (which column(s)).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem. Please, add some input and expected output